# Vuejs Gitlab page is blank, console says MIME type mismatch, css and js not found

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, mime-types, gitlab-ci

I made a website in Vuejs, it works on my local browser. I build the page locally and push to gitlab here (https://gitlab.com/ayaderaghul/coi6), and run CI (with folder: `public`). The page is blank (https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/), the console says:

```
The resource from “https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/public/static/js/vendor.d5bde172b988351183eb.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More] coi6

Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/public/static/js/vendor.d5bde172b988351183eb.js”.
```

And I right click the page to View Page Source, the link to css, js files are not found (view-source:https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/)

I have tried the following:

- I write commands to build the page in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: alpine:latest

before_script:
  - apk add --update nodejs
  - apk add --update npm
  - npm install chalk
  - npm install each-async
  - npm install indent-string
  - npm install

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

(https://gitlab.com/ayaderaghul/coi6/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)

- I change the css and js paths in file `index.html` in some ways: `/coi6/public/static/css/...` or `static/css/...` ...

None of them works. The behavior is the same. Please give me more options to try? Or more cues to look at? Or explain me something I haven't understood. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Your path is wrong in `index.html`.

Your files are available for example here :

https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/static/js/vendor.d5bde172b988351183eb.js

Whereas you are referencing them here :

https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/public/static/js/vendor.d5bde172b988351183eb.js

Comment: Thanks, now the console only warns (not errors) and I click the js/css link it shows the file. But the page is still blank (https://ayaderaghul.gitlab.io/coi6/). Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: now everything seems fine on the gitlab pages side, try to run your app in dev mode to see some more info from vuejs `npm run build --mode dev`

Comment: ```npm run dev``` on my local computer it works fine, just says a warning ```(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) <router-link v-for="button in buttons">: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys. See https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key for more info.```

Comment: As I said before, It looks OK on the gitlab pages side so I suggest closing this question and opening another one purely related to the vuejs problem.